# Pausing sounds with SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming, soundcloud

I'm fairly new to JS and I'm having trouble getting audio that is currently playing to pause or stop using the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK. I'm using a MEAN stack.

In the 'ready' function I initialize the SC player:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "my_client_ID",
    redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
});

...

$('#trackList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkplaytrack', playTrack);
$('#trackList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkpausetrack', pauseTrack);
```

The playTrack function works fine and audio starts playing:

```
function playTrack(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
        sound.play();
    });
};
```

But for some reason the pauseTrack function doesn't work:

```
function pauseTrack(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
        sound.pause();
    });
};
```

Any help, insights or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call SC.stream, you're creating a new sound object. pause() is working, just on a different sound than the one playing. You can store the stream to be used later:

```
var stream;

function playTrack(event) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!stream) {
    SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
        stream = sound;
        stream.play();
    });
  }
  else {
   stream.play();
  }
}


function pauseTrack(event) {
  if(stream) {
    stream.pause();
  }
}
```